semantic versioning using action semantic-release-action in github thorws error
I have this setup, in GitHub.
Main --> Release --> Feature/*
so, developer will develop features in feature branch using semantic versioning action cycjimmy/semantic-release-action@v4 which will create a package using -next.1 .
before introducing this way of working we always used Release as a Pre-Prd tag and tested in UAT environment with Tag X.X.X.
So, now if I introduce feature way of working, Github action is complaining tag 1.0.0 already exists when it should create a tag vX.X.X-next.1 because of feature branch.
So does anybody know how to fix this?
I'm committing the feature change as feat.
.releaserc file:
{
"branches": [
   { 
        "name": "main"
    },
    {
        "name": "release",
        "channel": "release",
        "prerelease": "release"
    },
    {
        "name": "feature/*",
        "prerelease": "next",
        "channel": "next"
    }
],
"plugins": [
    "@semantic-release/commit-analyzer",
    "@semantic-release/release-notes-generator",
    [
        "@semantic-release/changelog",
        {
            "changelogFile": "CHANGELOG.md"
        }
    ],
    [
        "@semantic-release/git",
        {
            "assets": [
                "CHANGELOG.md"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "@semantic-release/github"

]

}
and my workflow file build.yaml looks like this
name: Build Pre-release CI
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - feature/test

jobs:
  test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v4
        with:
          persist-credentials: true

      - name: Set up Python
        uses: actions/setup-python@v4
        with:
          python-version: '3.9'

      - name: Run Semantic Release for Feature 
        id: semantic_release_feature
        uses: cycjimmy/semantic-release-action@v4
        with:
          branch: ${{ github.ref_name }}
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GH_TOKEN }}

      - name: Extract release version from tag
        id: get_version
        run: |
          RELEASE_VERSION=${{ steps.semantic_release_feature.outputs.new_release_version }}
          echo "RELEASE_VERSION=$RELEASE_VERSION" >> $GITHUB_ENV

      - name: Run Python tests
        run: |
          python -m unittest discover

      - name: Update setup.py version
        run: |
          sed -i "s/version='.*'/version='${{ env.RELEASE_VERSION }}'/" setup.py
          cat setup.py

      - name: Commit version update
        run: |
          git config --global user.email "ci-bot@users.noreply.github.com"
          git config --global user.name "ci-bot"
          git remote set-url origin https://x-access-token:${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}@github.com/${{ github.repository }}.git
          git add setup.py
          git commit -m "chore(release): bump version to ${{ env.RELEASE_VERSION }}"
          git push origin ${{ github.ref_name }}
   

